# CodeIgniter mod_rewrite gives 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-url

I have written a CodeIgniter application and I want to use mod_rewrite to clean up my URL's. I have installed the CodeIgniter application in htdocs/ci-intro/

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci_intro/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I altered the config.php in CodeIgniter to the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Whenever I use my links to go to the about page I get a 404 message from CodeIgniter. The URL in my browser seems to be 'cleaned up' though (index.php is removed). This is the URL:

'http://localhost:8888/ci_intro/about'

Can anybody help me getting rid of the 404 error and actually directing the use to the about page?

OS: MAC OS X 10.8.2 (latest) 
SERVER SOFTWARE: MAMP  
PHP: 5.2.17  
BROWSERS: Chrome & Safari (In both browsers this problem occurs)

Comment: did enable mod_rewrite in apache, which kind of localhost server you have installed, for example: xampp ?

Comment: Mohammad, I have mod-rewrite enabled in apache. The software I am using is MAMP.

Comment: i think the problem is not with your rewrite conditions, becouase mod_rewrite will force two kind of errors ( as i know) if there is any problem with conditions. the first is 1- infinity redirect loops, 2- 500 server error. i'm still think there is something wrong about your mod_rewrite configuration. i had reviewed your conditions statement above, but every thing seems working fine.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing. Then it might be in my server configuration you think? Because then I will recheck it all.

Comment: Your htaccess looks okay. Please try it once removing the `RewriteBase ` directive. Also make sure that you have controller named `About`

Comment: I have this same exact error, were you able to fix it?

Comment: Allright I was able to fix it. I made a very stupid mistake: I didn't always use echo base_url() but just directly referred to localhost. Well in that case on gets the ugly URLs with index.php. So simple solution for me: always use echo base_url().

Answer (score 1):

Before reviewing your server configration, please try code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci_intro/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you again Mohammad. Unfortunately, it didn't work. It might be in some of the server configuration. But I have no idea what it might be...

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Your_folder_Name/index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Your_folder_Name/index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Your_folder_Name/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally I am using the same configuration like yours, and end up it didn't really work no matter how i change it.

So I gave up changing it and tried another simplest setting.
Try this out, it works for me!! :)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# If the start of the URL doesn't match one of these...
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|cache|images|uploads)

# Route through index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
```

probably isn't going to trigger, since REQUEST_URI starts with /. Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system
```

Ditto for

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
```

And does your system really want /index.php?/blah blah? It's going to expect a URL Query String after the ?.