# Cannot Remove index.php from the URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have been pulling my hair out for three days, I have googled everything, been on the code igniter forums and checked stack overflow from top to bottom.

All i want to do is remove the index.php from the url's. The closest post I found to my problem was not answered:
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214842/codeigniter-mod-rewrite-gives-404-error)

If i go to `localhost/CodeIgniter` my main page is shown. if i click my links i get an error that the page does not exist.

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Based on everything i have read, here is my current configuration.

MAC OSX 10.8.3
MAMP
CodeIgniter 2.1.3

My root directory is www/CodeIgniter/
Here is the .htaccess file that is in the CodeIgniter Root

```
#Deny from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Here is the config setup for CodeIgniter: I tried every setting for uri_protocol with no success

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I verified that I have mod_rewrite enabled and that AllowOverride is set to All in httpd.conf.

****UPDATE
so I deleted MAMP and codeigniter and started from scratch. Now with the .htaccess file below, when i go to localhost the codeigniter folder is not shown. If i try to browse to the folder I get the following error.

```
    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

when i looked in the error log, i have the following error.

```
[Mon Apr 22 21:42:51 2013] [alert] [client ::1] /Users/me/Dropbox/www/codeigniter/.htaccess: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules
```

I verified that I have mod_rewrite enabled in my phpinfo();

If i remove the .htaccess file I can browse to the folder and get the main page but of course the links don't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /codeigniter/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: two hours and nothing? im very surprised

Comment: Just for testing purposes, back up your current htaccess file and replace it with this and see if you can browse around without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never but I had to modify my httpd.conf file, after like three restarts it just started working. Maybe this can help someone else

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing purposes back up your htaccess file, then clear it completely and paste in this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

See if you can browse the site without error.

Comment: I updated my .htaccess and i still get the error when i click any of my links. Here are what my links look like just in case. <a href="<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>">About</a>

Answer (score 0):

Hey why don't you do one thing... download this code igniter installation https://github.com/amitavroy/cleanplate and then check if this is coming without error. You mod_rewrite should be on offcourse

Comment: I am downloading it now. mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Your template opens to the homepage but none of the links work.

Comment: Using my controllers and views that is

Comment: strange... can you share you code? I mean I have used this clean plate in so many projects and on so many servers.

Comment: no problem, you want my controller, view and model? I don't know why index.php is listed anyway if everyone removes it.

Comment: would it make sense that I need a Virtual Host? I have seen that as an option

Comment: The virtual host configuration is an add on. Good to have but not necessary. Is it possible for you to put that code on Github or something... I would have to look at the .htaccess file, the config file, your controller...

Comment: sure, ill add it later today

Comment: is there any permissions on the .htaccess that might be preventing it from working?

Comment: permission - no man I don't think so... if there is something wrong with the .ht file then it's a diff issue. Otherwise no. Are you using WAMP?

Comment: Im using MAMP, I verified that if I put deny all in the .htaccess it prevents me from seeing the file so I know its working. Since its installed in a folder in my root, if I change the ReriteBase directive nothing changes. I thought it would fail

Comment: Hey... then the best thing is to share the folder on git or some other place. Let me have a look and then I will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Inside Config file:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; //or 'QUERY_STRING'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I still get the 404 error if i click link but the homepage comes up fine. the links now add index.php which is the opposite of what i wanted.

Comment: @Drewdin: As I mentioned in the comment below `site_url()` will append "index.php" to the `base_url()`. `site_url('about') = your_base_url/index.php/about`. But if U use `base_url('about') = your_base_url/about`.

Comment: But If you have already used `site_url()` in lots of places then in config.php remove index.php `$config['index_page'] = '';`.

Comment: i haven't, my page is basic and I am just learning. I only have two views at this point. What is the correct way of using links to remove index.php, I was just following the Manual.

Comment: As said in config file U've set `$config['index_page']` to empty, then `site_url()` will not append index.php... But if U use `base_url()` U don't have 2 worry about this unless U manually define it in config file with `index.php`.

Comment: Having said that When U've removed index.php from ur links, U've to make sure that this is handled in `.htaccess` file. I found this solution to work perfectly for many and also for me. That's Y I suggested this. But I dunno why its not working for U...

Comment: I just deleted MAMP and codeigniter and now I am going to start from scratch. wish me luck

Comment: I have it on my lcoal machine, i took a few days off and I am going to look at it again tonight. I'll let you know what i find

Answer (score 0):

Just paste following in your .htaccess file it will work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CodeIgniter/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Set
$config['index_page'] = ''; //config.php
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';//config.php