# codeigniter - loading a function when clicking button

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problems loading  the function login_validation once i click the login button, i get the 404 error saying it's not found. I have included the code from the two relevant pages below.

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <?php
    echo form_open('main/login_validation');
    echo validation_errors();
    echo "<p>Email: ";
    echo form_input('email');
    echo "</p>";
    echo "<p>Password: ";
    echo form_password('password');
    echo "</p>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login');
    echo "</p>";
    echo form_close();
  ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {
    $this->login();
  }

  public function login() {
    $this->load->view('login');
  }

  public function members() {
    $this->load->view('members');
  }

  public function login_validation() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xsss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
      redirect('main/members');
    }
    else {
      $this->load->view('login');
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this function isn't working correctly?!

Comment: Do you have import form helper? `$this->load->helper('form');` And you should add controller's `contructor`.

Comment: I have $autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url'); in the autoload.php file

Answer (score 1):

are you sure your getting the 404 on the login_validation() and not because it can't find the library in `$this->load->library('form_validation');`?

Try removing all lines from the login_validation() function and simply put "`echo inside login_validation();`" see if your still getting the 404

Also try changing `echo form_open('main/login_validation');` to -> `echo form_open('main/login_validation'/);` Note the forward slash on the end

**Edit:** after looking at the tutorials your following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmKm1gCgUoM) episode 1 through 3. It seems the problem your having is very possibly related to either a typo or an issue with using mod rewrite and .HTACCESS

Firstly I suggest deleting the HTACCESS file for now ( or renaming temporarily) and test if things work. Then go back and follow step one of the tutorial again. Where he is explaining to replace the `RewriteBase` make sure your replacing correctly. I believe in your case it should be `/ci_intro/`. it needs to be the path to your code igniter directory. but regardless before doing that simply remove .HTACCESS and confirm it works.

**Edit 2:** it seems HTACCESS is an issue in that tutorial i can see several people complaining in the youtube comments. I suggest you just start fresh and try a new tutorial.

This tutorial is only "40minutes long" and seems far more current (DEC 2013) See how you go with that. Let me know how you get on :)

http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/codeigniter-tutorial-learn-codeigniter-in-40-minutes/

Comment: The requested URL /~1103884/ci_intro/main/login_validation was not found on this server.

Comment: Once i fill in the form and click login i get that error

Comment: whats the exact url your using to access the `login` screen?

Comment: that seems odd, can you put `echo "inside login()";` within your main controller's login function and see if it echo's anything on the login screen?. I mean what seems odd, is that I cannot access your main controller at all from the URL you provided...

Comment: public function login()
 {
  $this->load->view('login');
  echo "inside login()";
 }

Comment: are you doing anything with mod rewrite? see this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214842/codeigniter-mod-rewrite-gives-404-error)

Comment: Ok i'm quite certain that you made some sort of mistake with the mod rewrite (.HTACESS) step (or there is an issue in tutorial). Did you follow tutorial 1 and 2 exactly? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-gk1n2KWiY

Comment: Just for now, could I suggest just renaming .HTACCESS to .HTACCESS_OLD for now just to test quickly. (or delete completely).

Comment: I'm not using htaccess as i couldn't get it working correctly

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I can really help anymore on this one. What I do suggest is to start a different tutorial. I actually noticed many people complaining that HTACCESS isn't working anymore for code igniter in the way he's using in that video tutorial your using. (myself I don't actually use modrewrite anyway with CI). I suggest possibly just try a new tutorial such as this one - http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/codeigniter-tutorial-learn-codeigniter-in-40-minutes/ Just start fresh and see how you go

Answer (score 0):

Are you removing your index.php from the url?

I had a server (iis 6) fail at rewrite rules, so your link

```
/~1103884/ci_intro/main/login_validation
```

would be

```
/~1103884/ci_intro/index.php/main/login_validation
```

This means your form link should reflect the full path

**edited: put index.php in wrong spot*

Comment: that looks better, try that OP - http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1103884/ci_intro/index.php/main/ this is now returning a CI error page instead of standard 404. This looks like you've deleted the main controller. if you put that back it should work again. So i think the whole issue is that you were following paths which assumed HTACCESS is being used but because you skipped that step it means the tutorial is not compatible for  you

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in string:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xsss_clean');
```

'xsss_clean' - may be codeigniter trying to find unexisting filter and this results an error.
Try to fix this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
```