# Codignator Error File Not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hey I have been facing problem in codeignitor "File Not Found" in every controller. I faced in on Project,I fixed it by putting this code in .Htacces

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Then again faced this on another project automatically.

Comment: have you removed index.php from config.php `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

Comment: @NishantNair I have already added the anwser

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214842/codeigniter-mod-rewrite-gives-404-error)

Answer (score 0):

Solve This by putting this code in hatccess
Source : https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```